# Typescript conditionally optional callback for specific generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I know there are numerous issues on StackOverflow about conditionally optional types in TypeScript, but none answered my question.

I have the following `sum()` function that takes an array and a callback. The callback should be optional only if the array is `number[]`.

```js
function sum<T>(iter: T[], callback?: (arg: T) => number): number {
    return callback
        ? iter.reduce((sum, element) => sum + callback(element), 0)
        : iter.reduce((sum, x) => sum + Number(x), 0);  // <- I want to get rid of Number()
}
```

While this code works, it implies that any `T` could be converted to a number (which I don't want), while when `T` is a number, it does a redundant cast.

My best attempt at fixing this with overloads is:

```js
type OptionalIfNumber<T, U> = T extends number ? U | undefined : U;

export function sum(iter: number[], callback?: undefined): number;
export function sum<T>(iter: T[], callback: (arg: T) => number): number;
export function sum<T>(iter: T[], callback: OptionalIfNumber<T, (arg: T) => number>): number {
    return callback
        ? iter.reduce((sum, element) => sum + callback(element), 0)
        : iter.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x, 0);  // <- Problem is here
}
```

It seems that TypeScript does not know that the only time `callback` is `undefined`, `T` must extend `number`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to get the compiler to follow your logic is to make the function take a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions), which is immediately [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

This lets the compiler see the `[iter, callback]` pair as a [destructured discriminated union](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) where `callback` is the discriminant property.  Like this:

```
function sum<T>(...[iter, callback]:
    [iter: number[], callback?: undefined] |
    [iter: T[], callback: (arg: T) => number]
): number {
    return callback ?
        iter.reduce((sum, element) => sum + callback(element), 0) // okay
        : iter.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x, 0);  // okay
}
```

The above call signature says that the `[iter, callback]` pair is either of type `[number, undefined?]` or of type `[T[], (arg: T)=>number]`.  Inside the implementation, when `callback` is truthy, the compiler automatically narrows `iter` to `T[]` and `callback` to `(arg: T)=>number`.  Otherwise, it narrows `iter` to `number[]` and `callback` to `undefined`.  So your conditional expression works in both cases.

When you call it, IntelliSense displays it like an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
sum([4, 3, 2]);
// 1/2 sum(iter: number[], callback?: undefined): number;

sum(["a", "bc", "def"], x => x.length);
// 2/2 sum(iter: string[], callback: (arg: string) => number): number
```

So it doesn't change very much from the caller's side, either.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwDwBUB8AKAOiIG0YoBTAJwBpEIBDAG0YCN6IBrAXQC4BYAFCJhiUhUo9EYdCyrEutBszacA-JPAATcsBhhymrogA+gkaLJVJWeYqat2HSXnqUA5tYCUiALw4pMlRcgp6S0miylIgA3mYilORQIJRISg6ciKpx5sKWlAQJmiAQ5Hh4qGi05IzkaORgUN5+KOiIANR09ioceNW19Y20AAzeAPSjiHAc9ACe2TmSeQUGxaXl6LQAHk3+Fe2Im8OeANzC45PTcwIAvoKCEAjIcDUEjHBu62h4xAAstADMtAATFxPGMJgBOQTnACMoyBLS+eTCgUotk6ykc6kQWh0egMoQCESox3uj2e5Fe70+3wARPRabRaSwIIzELTtMBaQoDr5-JtXvU3FAABZg07nABs0ImQPhiLwyJQUEoejc6LS3Wcrg8ytVYDcOyJkUJ4UidwEQA)

Comment: XO gives the following error on the return statement: "Unsafe return of an `any` typed value. (@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return)" Any idea how to fix this? This is the first time I'm using XO--I thought it was a "plug and play" type linter/formatter, but it seems like it can be a pain which is a bit disappointing.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue with TS2349 by replacing the two `iter.reduce()` with `(iter as T[]).reduce()` and `(iter as number[]).reduce()`, respectively. Could you edit the answer so other people may see the solution?